# Writing to a file with multiprocessing

Tags: python, file-io, queue, multiprocessing

I'm having the following problem in python.

I need to do some calculations in parallel whose results I need to be written sequentially in a file. So I created a function that receives a `multiprocessing.Queue` and a file handle, do the calculation and print the result in the file:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from mySimulation import doCalculation   

# doCalculation(pars) is a function I must run for many different sets of parameters and collect the results in a file

def work(queue, fh):
while True:
    try:
        parameter = queue.get(block = False)
        result = doCalculation(parameter) 
        print >>fh, string
    except:
        break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nthreads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    fh = open("foo", "w")
    workQueue = Queue()
    parList = # list of conditions for which I want to run doCalculation()
    for x in parList:
        workQueue.put(x)
    processes = [Process(target = writefh, args = (workQueue, fh)) for i in range(nthreads)]
    for p in processes:
       p.start()
    for p in processes:
       p.join()
    fh.close()
```

But the file ends up empty after the script runs. I tried to change the worker() function to:

```
def work(queue, filename):
while True:
    try:
        fh = open(filename, "a")
        parameter = queue.get(block = False)
        result = doCalculation(parameter) 
        print >>fh, string
        fh.close()
    except:
        break
```

and pass the filename as parameter. Then it works as I intended. When I try to do the same thing sequentially, without multiprocessing, it also works normally.

Why it didn't worked in the first version? I can't see the problem.

Also: can I guarantee that two processes won't try to write the file simultaneously?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks. I got it now. This is the working version:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep
from random import uniform

def doCalculation(par):
    t = uniform(0,2)
    sleep(t)
    return par * par  # just to simulate some calculation

def feed(queue, parlist):
    for par in parlist:
            queue.put(par)

def calc(queueIn, queueOut):
    while True:
        try:
            par = queueIn.get(block = False)
            print "dealing with ", par, "" 
            res = doCalculation(par)
            queueOut.put((par,res))
        except:
            break

def write(queue, fname):
    fhandle = open(fname, "w")
    while True:
        try:
            par, res = queue.get(block = False)
            print >>fhandle, par, res
        except:
            break
    fhandle.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nthreads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    fname = "foo"
    workerQueue = Queue()
    writerQueue = Queue()
    parlist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    feedProc = Process(target = feed , args = (workerQueue, parlist))
    calcProc = [Process(target = calc , args = (workerQueue, writerQueue)) for i in range(nthreads)]
    writProc = Process(target = write, args = (writerQueue, fname))


    feedProc.start()
    for p in calcProc:
        p.start()
    writProc.start()

    feedProc.join ()
    for p in calcProc:
        p.join()
    writProc.join ()
```

Comment: Please focus.  One set of code **only**.  Please remove obsolete or irrelevant code.  Please avoid using "Edit".  Just get the question to be perfectly clear, complete and consistent, please.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You really should use two queues and three separate kinds of processing.

1. Put stuff into Queue #1.
2. Get stuff out of Queue #1 and do calculations, putting stuff in Queue #2.  You can have many of these, since they get from one queue and put into another queue safely.
3. Get stuff out of Queue #2 and write it to a file.  You must have exactly 1 of these and no more.  It "owns" the file, guarantees atomic access, and absolutely assures that the file is written cleanly and consistently.

Comment: +1 for worker and consumer queues. Remember to set a maxsize on the queue or your workers may eat your memory and starve the writer.

Comment: Oh nevermind about the multiple runs... I'm stupid enough not to notice that I launched the feedProc and writProc multiple times. ¬¬ I corrected the code. But I still got an empty file.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it. I launched the process who would write in the file before I had any results... it works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is looking for a simple way to do the same, this can help you.
I don't think there are any disadvantages to doing it in this way. If there are, please let me know.

```
import multiprocessing 
import re

def mp_worker(item):
    # Do something
    return item, count

def mp_handler():
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(cpus)
    # The below 2 lines populate the list. This listX will later be accessed parallely. This can be replaced as long as listX is passed on to the next step.
    with open('ExampleFile.txt') as f:
        listX = [line for line in (l.strip() for l in f) if line]
    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
        for result in p.imap(mp_worker, listX):
            # (item, count) tuples from worker
            f.write('%s: %d\n' % result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    mp_handler()
```

Source: [Python: Writing to a single file with queue while using multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596714/python-writing-to-a-single-file-with-queue-while-using-multiprocessing-pool)

Comment: This is the simplest way I have found for using multiprocessing in general. Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the write worker code, if the block is false, the worker will never get any data. Should be as follows:

```
par, res = queue.get(block = True)
```

You can check it by adding line

```
 print "QSize",queueOut.qsize()
```

after the 
`queueOut.put((par,res))`

With block=False you would be getting ever increasing length of the queue until it fills up, unlike with block=True where you get always "1".