# No writing for a simple Python multiprocessing and a message queue?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, message-queue, pool

I am trying to parallelize a for loop and write results to a text file.
Here is my code based on these SO answers:

- [Python: Writing to a single file with queue while using multiprocessing Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596714/python-writing-to-a-single-file-with-queue-while-using-multiprocessing-pool)
- [Python multiprocessing safely writing to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file)

```py
#multiprocessing version
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from functools import partial

fn = './rules_res_3.txt'

def worker(arg, q):
    '''stupidly simulates long running process'''
    w1, w2, w3= arg
    res=str(w1) +" " + str(w2) + " " + str(w3) 
    q.put(res)
    return res

def listener(q):
    '''listens for messages on the q, writes to file. '''

    with open(fn, 'a') as f:
        while True:
            m = q.get()
            print(m)
            if m == 'kill':
                break
            f.write(m + '\n')
            # f.flush()

def run():
    #must use Manager queue here, or will not work
    # manager = mp.Manager()
    # q = manager.Queue()    
    # pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() + 2)

    #put listener to work first
    # watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

    #fire off workers
    r1,r2,r3 = np.arange(0.9, 1.5, 0.1), np.arange(0.9, 1.1, 0.1), np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    params=product(r1, r2, r3)
    

    # pool.map(partial(worker, q=q), [arg for arg in params])
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        pool = mp.Pool()  # By default pool will size depending on cores available
        message_queue = manager.Queue()  # Queue for sending messages to file writer listener
        pool.apply_async(listener, (message_queue, ))  # Start file listener ahead of doing the work
        pool.map(partial(worker, q=message_queue), params)  # Partial function allows us to use map to divide workload


    #now we are done, kill the listener
    # q.put('kill')
    # pool.close()
    # pool.join()

run()
```

Problems that I am having:

- `print` in `listener` function doesn't print anything
  [image]
- this program doesn't write to `'./rules_res_3.txt'` at all. I am not even sure whether `workers` or `listener` is running properly at all.

Comment: What is your OS and output by `python xxx.py`? You  should protect the “entry point” of the program by using `if __name__ == '__main__'` according to the 
[Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines)

Comment: @HALF9000 I am using windows and running this piece of code on jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you never allow the loop to end.  You have commented out the code that sends the "kill" signal, which is what `listener` uses to end.  Without that, the file is never flushed.

This works:

```
def run():
    r1,r2,r3 = np.arange(0.9, 1.5, 0.1), np.arange(0.9, 1.1, 0.1), np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
    params=product(r1, r2, r3)
    
    with mp.Manager() as manager:
        pool = mp.Pool()  # By default pool will size depending on cores available
        message_queue = manager.Queue()  # Queue for sending messages to file writer listener
        pool.apply_async(listener, (message_queue, ))  # Start file listener ahead of doing the work
        pool.map(partial(worker, q=message_queue), params)  # Partial function allows us to use map to divide workload

        #now we are done, kill the listener
        message_queue.put('kill')
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```